# Analog off board connectivity

Tags: analog, signal

I have a board that I intend to control with high fidelity differential analog, I'm aiming at one part in 2<sup>16</sup>.

I want to connect the two boards with a COTS connector that solves most of the pick-up problems, without the cost.  I am considering using a SATA cable since it appears to be twisted pair and shielded.

Are there any issues using COTS digital hardware to run analog signals?  If so what would you suggest instead for COTS analog connections?

Comment: If you are worried about electrostatic pickup via the cable then pay attention to the shield.  A 90% braid may not be enough.  I needed to use a cable to connect a low noise signal and needed a cable with both braid and aluminized mylar.  Well that was for something with a relatively high source impedance. (1k - 100k range) If you're driving the signal lines with a good stiff source then perhaps it's not a problem.

Comment: I hope to drive it with a DAC - I haven't picked a specific part yet.  I clearly will need to match impedance, and maybe using a differential driver would help control this better.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a sound approach to me as long as you are working with low voltages and sea-level/room-temp environment. You should make sure you understand the impedance of the SATA cable and that you are matching the impedance of the traces on your board and that you have a matched load. This is especially important if your signal includes high frequencies.

Also, you may want to make sure that nobody confuses your connector for a normal SATA connector, especially if there is potential to damage your system by doing so. I would consider adding some sort of additional keying, if possible, or at least add a warning label.